# Share data between pages without Provider package

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I was hoping if there was a way to sent products to cart when we press the add to cart button with out the provider package on Flutter.

This is what my cart single product looks like:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: new Text(CartProductName),
        leading: Image.asset(CartProductPicture),
        subtitle: new Text("${CartProductPrice} ETB"),
        trailing: new Text(CartProductQuantity, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since pages are also widgets, you can just pass the data with the constructor. However, for complex apps, without any architectural pattern or [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) solution codebase will be impossible to maintain or test.

**Example**

Let's say we have pages P1 and P2. We initialize the stream on P1, then pass it to the P2 with the constructor. Now P2 listens the stream and when P1 sends data it gets updated. In case we want to add P3 that uses the same stream, we need to pass it with the constructor again.

Better way is to have the logic out of widgets. Lets have an imaginary class called `Data`. If every widget depend on `Data` then they will not need each other anymore. P1 can use `Data.add()` and other pages can use `Data.listen()`. This is just one benefit of getting the logic out of the widgets.

Provider widget provides business logic to the decendant widgets. We initialize the provider with `Data` and all of the pages under provider can now access the `Data`.

Comment: I would use change notifier and pass it to the other page with constructor. But this is not a recommended way. Your code will be out of hand soon.

Comment: what do you mean out of hand

Comment: okay so if provider is the best was to do it how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid provider, and still store data you can use couple of alternatives:

1. Local storage plugin called [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), that stores data as key-value pairs, where you can store your object as a JSON string.
2. Construct [singleton](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-design-patterns-1-singleton-437f04e923ce) class which will hold your cart data, that can be accessed throughout the app without needing any context information to modify cart contents.